# ¿Es aconsejable hacer un endpoind especifico para guardar imágenes en nodeJS?

Tags: nodejs, api, express, patrones-de-diseño, buenas-prácticas

¿Es aconsejable hacer un endpoind especifico para guardar imágenes?.

Estaba analizando un poco el código de una API en node, y el endpoind de guardado creo que podría simplemente se una función que de pase a otras entidades como usuarios o productos las cuales cada una tienen una imagen, y desperto mi curiosidad realmente es cual es la mejor practica o la mejor forma manejar esto del guardado. Por ejemplo pienso en estas opciones:

1- Crear un enpoint especifico para guardar imágenes y el frontend debe manejarlo con algún servicio que encadene la peticion la creación de un usuario o producto y posteriormente el guardado de imagenes.

2- Implementarlo como una función de guardado que se aplique en los enpoint de usuario y productos al crearse estos que tambien haga un guardado de la imagen si esta es enviada.

3- Un endpoind especifico para guardar y también hacer un PUT o POST encadena en los enpoind de usuario y producto para guardar la imagen.

No se si se entiende a lo que me refiero, pero basicamente quiero saber que es lo estandar o optimo para implementar el guardado de archivos.

Este es el codigo actual de endpoint del guardado de imagienes, es un poco extenso

```
/**dependencies */
const express = require('express');
const fileUpload = require('express-fileupload');
const fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path')
// models
const User = require('../../models/user.model')
const Ads = require('../../models/ads.model')

/**settings */
const app = express();
// File Uploads Middleware settings
app.use(fileUpload(fileUpload({ useTempFiles: true })));

app.put('/upload/:folder/:id', (req, res) => {

    const id = req.params.id
    const folderName = req.params.folder

    // if any files is sent
    if (!req.files || Object.keys(req.files).length === 0) {
        return res.status(400).json({
            ok: false,
            err: {
                message: 'a file name is required'
            }
        });
    }

    // if correct
    const Image = req.files.Image;

    //verify extension
    if (!verifyEXt(Image.name)) {
        return res.status(400).json({
            ok: false,
            err: {
                message: 'Just jpg, png or gif files allowed'
            }
        });
    }

    const ext = verifyEXt(Image.name)

    // if got a wrong path
    if (verifyFolder(folderName)) {
        return res.status(400).json({
            ok: false,
            err: {
                message: 'There is no such folder'
            }
        });
    }
    //if everything id ok mv() method saves the file
    const fileName = `${id}_${Date.now().toString()}.${ext}`;

    Image.mv(`uploads/${folderName}/${fileName}`, (err) => {
        if (err)
            return res.status(500).json({
                ok: false,
                err
            });

        // updateing the image in the document if everithing is ok
        updateImage(id, res, fileName, folderName)
    });
});

/**************************
 * verify, save and delete *
 * ***********************/

//vefify extension
const verifyEXt = (name) => {
    const ExtensionsAllowed = ['jpg', 'png', 'gif'];
    const cuttedName = name.split('.')
    const extension = cuttedName[cuttedName.length - 1];
    if (ExtensionsAllowed.indexOf(extension) < 0) {
        return false
    } else {
        return extension;
    }
}
// veryfy folder
const verifyFolder = (folderName) => {
    const allowedFolders = ['user_images', 'ads_images']
    if (allowedFolders.indexOf(folderName) < 0) {
        return false
    }
}

// delete old image
const deleteImage = (folder, imgPath) => {
    const pathImg = path.resolve(__dirname, `../../uploads/${folder}/${imgPath}`)
    //veryfy if exists the path and then go to delete it  with unlink function 
    if (fs.existsSync(pathImg)) {
        fs.unlinkSync(pathImg)
    }
    return
}

/******************
 * ImageSaver
 *****************/
const updateImage = (id, res, fileName, folderName) => {
    if (folderName === 'user_images') {
        User.findById(id, (err, userDB) => {
            if (err) {
                // it's allways saved even if there an error so it must be deleted            
                deleteImage(folderName, fileName)
                return res.status(500).json({
                    ok: false,
                    err
                });
            }

            if (!userDB) {            
                    return res.status(400).json({
                        ok: false,
                        err: {
                            message: 'User not Found'
                        }
                    });                
            }

            // delete the olg imagen
            deleteImage(folderName, userDB.img)

            userDB.img = fileName;
            userDB.save((err, savedUser,) => {

                // optional
                if (err) {
                    return res.status(500).json({
                        ok: false,
                        err
                    });
                }
                // if ok
                res.json({
                    ok: true,
                    img: savedUser.img
                })

            })
        });
    }
    else if (folderName === 'ads_images') {

        Ads.findById(id, (err, adsDB) => {
            
            if (err) {
                // it's allways saved even if there an error so it must be deleted            
                deleteImage(folderName, fileName)
                return res.status(500).json({
                    ok: false,
                    err
                });
            }

            if (!adsDB) {                
                    return res.status(400).json({
                        ok: false,
                        err: {
                            message: 'Ads not Found'
                        }
                    });                
            }

            // delete the old imagen
            deleteImage(folderName, adsDB.img)

            adsDB.img = fileName;

            adsDB.save((err, savedAds) => {
                // optional
                if (err) {
                    return res.status(500).json({
                        ok: false,
                        err
                    });
                }
                // if ok
                res.json({
                    ok: true,
                    img: savedAds.img
                })

            })
        });
    }
    else {
        return res.status(400).json({
            ok: false,
            err: {
                message: 'Folder is not correct'
            }
        });
    }
}
/*
Exports
*/
module.exports = app;
```

Y este el endpoint para guardar un usuario en una peticion POST

```
/*** POST ****/
app.post('/usuarios',[verifyToken, verifyAminRole], function (req, res) {

    const body = req.body;

    const user = new User({
        name: body.name,
        email: body.email,
        password: bcrypt.hashSync(body.password, 10),
        role: body.role
    })

    user.save((err, userDB) => {

        // if error
        if (err) {
            return res.status(400).json({
                ok: false,
                err
            })
        }

        // if success
        res.json({
            ok: true,
            user: userDB
        })
    })
})
```

Comment: Gerardo Este tipo de preguntas son basada en opiniones te recomiendo mas bien entrar al chat y debatir este tema con los expertos en el area

Comment: @JackNavaRow gracias amigo ¿como entro al chat?.

Comment: sea bienvendido al [chat]

Comment: Yo tuve esa misma duda y en esta pregunta ocurrió un buen debate sobre ese tema: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33279153/rest-api-file-ie-images-processing-best-practices

Comment: @Ezio gracias bro, excelente aporte.